# The simplest question: extract values from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So this is an example:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [title] => Title_1 [checkout] => 1 [no_gateway] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [title] => Title_2 [checkout] => 1 [no_gateway] => 1 )
[2] => Array ( [title] => Title_3 [checkout] => 0 [no_gateway] => 0 )
[3] => Array ( [title] => Title_4 [checkout] => 1 [no_gateway] => 1 )
[4] => Array ( [title] => Title_5 [checkout] => 0 [no_gateway] => 0 )
[5] => Array ( [title] => Title_6 [checkout] => 1 [no_gateway] => 0 )
)
```

I need to print out all values under [title] key having [checkout] => 1 & [no_gateway] => 0

In my case it should looks like

- Title_1
- Title_6

Please help php-beginner :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how you knew to tag this with `foreach` but didn't know how to actually do this.

Comment: Yes, I've searched a lot before and tried foreach too but with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $row) {
  if ($row['checkout'] && !$row['no_gateway']) {
    print $row['title'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  if($item['checkout'] == 1 && $item['no_gateway'] == 0) {
      echo $item['title'];
  }
}
```

assuming your array is called $items

Answer (score 3):

```
print_r(
    array_map(function ($a) { return $a["title"]; },
        array_filter($original,
            function ($a) { return $a["checkout"] && !$a["no_gateway"]; }
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hot damn, I didn't know you could declare lambda functions like that in php. No more stupid `create_function` calls or passing in functions as a string of their name.

Comment: @Jam It's a new feature in PHP 5.3. See http://pt.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Yep, thanks. Went to read about it after I saw this post. I saw it in a php web framework but thought they were using some hack.

Comment: Downvoted due to complexity of answer. The person asking this question was a complete newbie and this solution is definitely overkill.

Comment: @Ian The complexity is in your head. The reason it might seem complicated is because the syntax in PHP for lambda functions is quite verbose. If you could define one like in Mathematica `#^2&` instead of `function ($a) { return pow($a,2); }`, it would not seem so "complex".

Comment: @Artefacto - you missed my point. The fact that have an anonymous (or lambda) function nested inside two additional functions is not easily comprehendible to newbies. That'd be like teaching a kindergartner long division to solve a problem that be solved with simple subtraction.

Comment: @Ian That's condescending to the OP, who, by the way, is not the only target of this question; it's meant to be here for the posterity. Nevertheless, this is Programming 101 and is, in fact, a straightforward implementation: filter the wanted elements, transform the remaining ones.

Comment: @Artefacto Not trying to be condescending to the original poster, trying to help him. He claimed himself "Please help php-beginner :)"

Answer (score 2):

You tagged the question with the answer: `foreach`

```
// assuming $arr is the array containing the values from the example
foreach ($arr as $record) {
    if ($record['checkout'] && !$record['no_gateway']) {
        echo $record['title'], "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( $array as $value ) {
    if( $value["checkout"] == 1 && $value["no_gateway"] == 0 ) {
        print $value["title"].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```