# How to extract emails from a complex array

Tags: php, arrays

How could I get only emails in a simple array ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate question, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496378/the-simplest-question-extract-values-from-array?rq=1

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. Read the question...

Comment: Yes, that's not what you're looking for. You also ought to be looking for the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en). It's free, and it can be downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have them in a simple array in your first element.
So if the above construct is called $myArr, you have them in $myArr[0], stored as array of emails.

If you want them in another variable, do something like:

```
$myEmails = $myArr[0];
```